# Push to object instead of array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using underscore to extract some props into a separate object but the structure is not as I want:

```
let element = {
    foo: 0,
    bar: 1,
    baz: _.map(
            _.filter(element.properties, (prop) => 
                _.contains(validationProps, prop.name)), (rule) => 
                    ({ [rule.name]: rule.value }) )
}
```

.. returns an array of objects for `baz`:

```
[ {"required":true} , {"maxLength":242} ]
```

.. what I need however is:

```
{ "required":true, "maxLength":242 }
```

Comment: What does `element.properties` look like? Plus, element still doesn't exist when u refer to itself from inside itself. `element  = {a: '1', foo: element.a}` `element.foo` is undefined

Comment: @AbanaClara `[{"name":"label","value":"Short 2"},{"name":"required","value":true},{"name":"maxLength","value":242}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or use JavaScript's [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "label",
    "value": "Short 2"
  },
  {
    "name": "required",
    "value": true
  },
  {
    "name": "maxLength",
    "value": 242
  }
];

let reformatted = data.reduce((pv, cv) => {
  pv[cv.name] = cv.value;
  return pv;
}, {});

console.log(reformatted);
```

Comment: Incidentally, you can stick with underscore if you want. That has [reduce](https://underscorejs.org/#reduce) as well.

Comment: Yep, thats what I went with.